# Send me a (photo / picture) of (you/yours/yourself) please

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

Please imagine you're talking to someone through a community application on your phone like Skype. You want to see his / her face in various pics. I was wondering which option below sounds correct to you to be asked from that person:

> 1- Send me a (photo / picture) of **you** please. 
>  
>   2- Send me a (photo / picture) of **yours** please. 
>   3- Send me a (photo / picture) of **yourself** please.

To me, they all sound correct, and semantically and grammatically I see nothing wrong with each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To make this clear:** All options are possibly correct depending on context. However, in this context, **#3 is most appropriate.**

**#1 would be correct** if this sentence were not in the infinitive like.

"Look! This is a picture of you as a baby.

**#2 would be correct** if you had sent someone a picture of your car and wanted to see that person's car

"I've send you a picture of my Dodge Viper. Can you send me a picture of yours?"

#3 is the the correct answer here because you have the imperative (which) omits the pronoun but implies it. If you change the imperative to a modal you would get this:

"You should send a picture of yourself."

**Explanation:**

The rule is that if you already have pronoun then the next pronoun (referring to the same person/thing) needs to be reflexive. **Examples:**

"The dog bit itself."

"You see yourself in the mirror."

**In the same sense you get:**

"He refused to send me a picture of himself even though I sent him one of myself."

"One should think twice before uploading pictures of oneself."

When you have the imperative the pronoun is simply implied. Example of uses of the imperative in this way:

"Instructions:

1. Write a short description of yourself.
2. Upload a picture of yourself.
3. Click submit"

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an imperative sentence, the implied subject is *you*.

So, the object pronoun must be a **reflexive pronoun.**

A reflexive pronoun is used when the object of the verb is the same as the subject. Since the person is sending a picture of themselves, you would have to use the reflexive pronoun *yourself*.

*Of yours* implies possession, so if you were to ask "Send me a picture of yours", you would be asking for any picture that they had.

Using *you* is grammatically incorrect, however it still retains the same semantic value as the correct word, *yourself*, unlike *yours*.

As a sidenote, I would maybe add *Could you* or something of the like to the start of the sentence and phrase it as a question, as the recipient may take it to be a bit blunt if you aren't already close with them.

Comment: Thank you @hvhsh. So, #1 is incorrect, while both #2 and #3 work properly. But which one is preferred and why?

Comment: @A-friend If you want a picture of that person, you would go with number 3. When you say "of yours", it implies possession, so you would really only be asking for a picture which they had, and not necessarily of them.